# hammer.js can't handle / set tap and doubletap on same elements

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

when use the hammer.js default  'doubletap'

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style media="screen">
            .box {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">

        </div>
        <script src="js/hammer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var myElement = document.querySelector('.box')

            var hammer = new Hammer(myElement)

            hammer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
                console.log(e.type)
            }).on('tap', function (e) {
                console.log(e.type)
            })
        })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when I double tap, it print 'tap' twice, and 'doubletap' once, but I want it just print 'doubletap', don't fire the 'tap'.

I try requreFailure http://hammerjs.github.io/require-failure/ and [Hammer.js : How to handle / set tap and doubletap on same elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535088/hammer-js-how-to-handle-set-tap-and-doubletap-on-same-elements)

so I  write this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style media="screen">
        .box {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <script src="js/hammer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var myElement = document.querySelector('.box')

        var hammer = new Hammer(myElement)
        var singleTap = new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'singletap' });
        var doubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 });

        hammer.add([doubleTap, singleTap]);

        doubleTap.recognizeWith(singleTap);

        singleTap.requireFailure([doubleTap]);
        hammer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
            console.log(e.type)
        }).on('singletap', function (e) {
            console.log(e.type)
        })
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't console.log anything(even error message), it's really weird. The hammer's version is 2.0.8. sorry for my poor English, hope that's clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
var hammer = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
```

instead of

```
hammer = new Hammer(myElement).
```

Ciao.

Comment: This actually works. I will take a look at the sources of Hammer, because it is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var timeInMs = 0;
hammer.on('tap', function(e) {
    if((Date.now()-timeInMs)<300){
        //doubleTap
    }else{
        //tap
    }
    timeInMs = Date.now();
});
```